# Magento: Free shipping with Tablerates and Discount

Tags: table-rates

I'm currently using Magento 1.9.2.4 and have problem with free shipping with Tablerates in combination with discount code.

In the System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax I use:

**Apply Customer Tax - After Discount**

**Apply Discount on Prices - Including Tax**

That's working fine with everything I need. The problem is, that the discount amount is with tax and the value of the cart is without tax. For example:

I have free shipping from 39 €, the product costs 79,90 €, the coupon has a 50% discount and the product has 7% tax. In the Tablerates.php:

```
$request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() // 34.72 € - wrong!!! tax is subtracted from 79.90 and not from 39.95
```

after that I add the tax:

```
if (Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax()) {
   foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
      $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() + $item->getTaxAmount());
   }
}
```

and the final value of the cart is:

```
$request->getPackageValue() // 37.33 €
```

which is wrong. Because the value is under 39 € the shipping costs will be added :(

Any ideas how to solve the problem? I cannot change the tax configuration because the tax display in the frontend would be wrong.

Thank you!